# What does :scope "test" mean in build.boot dependency?

Tags: clojure

A lot of examples have dependencies written like

```
[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12" :scope "test"]
```

I think it means to not include this dependency in prod build, like lein's dev profile, but I can't find any documentation on this. What other scopes are available? Do they have hardcoded meaning within boot or is it something a user can define?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This translates directly to [Maven scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

For `test`:

> This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal
>   use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation
>   and execution phases. This scope is not transitive.

In boot these dependencies are excluded when you build a jar artifact. Also they do not count as transitive dependencies when you have a dependency on the project. This is also used to specify the Clojure version in a boot project:

> Libraries (including Boot tasks) shouldn't depend directly on a Clojure version. Instead, they should use :scope "provided" qualifier
>   with a Clojure dependency. This qualifier makes the dependency
>   non-transitive. Then the dependency works as a documentation about
>   required Clojure version.

[Source](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Setting-Clojure-version)